# RSA Encrypt in C# and Decrypt in nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, rsa

I've a client side which is running on C# and to encrypt the data with RSA public key and send over to Nodejs to decrypt. Everything works almost perfect except the data I decrypted is come with weird padding. I've tried all ways I've known before i ask here, so any help will be appreciated.

C#

```
UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\rsaKeys\\my-public-key.pem"))
using (var reader = new PemReader(stream))
{
   var rsaParameters = reader.ReadRsaKey();
   byte[] encryptedData;
   using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
   {
       RSA.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
       encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
   }
   return encryptedData;
}
```

NodeJs

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(val, 'base64');
const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
  {
    key: this.rsaPrivateKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
  },buffer);
let rtn = decrypted.toString('utf8');
```

the decrypted data will become `{ " h e l l o " : " w o r l d " }` instead. Any idea why would this happen?

Comment: `UnicodeEncoding` uses 2 bytes per character (UTF-16) whereas you are decoding the bytes in NodeJs as if they were 1 byte per character (UTF-8).

Comment: Encodings matter. You're telling the C# to use UTF16 and the nodejs to use UTF8.

Comment: thanks for all your help, it's really appreciated! you guys are awesome!

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar. My question to you is how is "this.rsaPrivateKey" initialized? I don't see any code that initializes this required parameter. I have the XML formatted private key needed for the decryption (and does work on the C# side) but am struggling to figure out to get the NodeJS code to correctly use it. Thx.